# Convert date format of dojo datetextbox using jquery

Tags: jquery, date, dojo

I have to convert my date format to be understandable by dojo.

How can I convert (getting it via json)

```
 14-JAN-14 (dd-MM-yy)
```

to

```
2014-01-14 (to be set this as default value in dojo date textbox)
```

using JQuery?

Tried like below

```
var currentDate = new Date('14-JAN-14');
currentDate = currentDate.getFullYear()+"-"+ currentDate.getMonth()+1 +"-"+currentDate.getDate();

alert(currentDate);
```

but it is showing Nan-Nan1-Nan

Any help? thanks

Comment: I remember that I have given the answer this question (earlier you have asked something similar). But it's working with normal javascript code. Look at here http://jsfiddle.net/5GzNe/

Comment: May be.. but is not working for me. I am using zend framework, may be this is point to be noted.

Comment: It depends on the browser. It works in Google Chrome for me, but it doesn't work in Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The funniest part is that this code actually works in Google Chrome, but it doesn't work for Mozilla Firefox (for me at least).
Mozilla Firefox has problems with the dashes (`-`) and the year not being fully written (`14` in stead of `2014`).

So you could try to convert that:

```js
function convertDate(/** String */ dateStr) {
    var months = ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"];
    var parts = dateStr.split("-");
    return new Date(2000 + parseInt(parts[2]), months.indexOf(parts[1]), parseInt(parts[0]));
}
```

What this actually does is split your date and use the `new Date(year, month, day)` constructor to get a new `Date` object.

Of course you need to change the year from `14` to `2014` (you could add `2000` to it) and you need to convert the month from `"JAN"` to `0`, `"FEB"` to `1`, ... (it's zero-based) which you can do by creating an array and getting the index of the matching item using `indexOf()`.